# Map with more than 3k Markers

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, gmlib

I'm trying to draw a map with a lot of markers on it. Just say more than 3000 markers, and this is taking a very long time to process and is using a lot of memory.

But I have the same map on Google Earth and this open very quickly. Somebody knows a way to speedup the process using gmLib?

Comment: I forget to say that I'm using Delphi 7...

Comment: The trick to doing something fast is usually not to do it at all. Does Google really show you *thousands* of markers at once? Is any human being capable of taking in 3,000 of them at once?

Comment: Yes, it shows (not Maps is Google Earth)... The markers are electricity masts in a city, for where my network goes, and I like to find some location doing a zoom and look directly on the map.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [RTree structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree).

> R-trees are tree data structures used for spatial access methods,
>   i.e., for indexing multi-dimensional information such as geographical
>   coordinates, rectangles or polygons.
>
> A common real-world usage for an R-tree might be to store spatial
>   objects such as restaurant locations or the polygons that typical maps
>   are made of: streets, buildings, outlines of lakes, coastlines, etc.
>   and then find answers quickly to queries such as "Find all museums
>   within 2 km of my current location", "retrieve all road segments
>   within 2 km of my location"

Queries like the one you expect will become almost *immediate*... :)

I use the [RTree extension available in SQLite3](http://www.sqlite.org/rtree.html). Our Open Source framework [interfaces this kind of virtual tables with Delphi classes](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/06/02/TSQLRecordRTree-to-implement-R-Tree-virtual-tables). BTW it works from Delphi 6 up to XE5.

If you are afraid of using a RTree, just ordering the data in order will help a lot searching e.g. via a [binary search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Comment: I liked your sugestion, and I will try this, but here is not the case. I really want to draw all markers and give to user the possibility of make a zoom on map and see each one more closely. The purpose is to enable one visual search presenting all possibilities and let the user chose one. 
I tryed disable the AutoUpdate property, this really speedup the entire process, but after that I can't find the right way to reload the map.